# Count incoming and outgoing edges from a given vertex to each neighbour in a multidigraph

Tags: graph, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to find a query that would allow me to get a sort of group count of incoming and outgoing vertices of a vertex in a multidigraph.

[image]

Taking the graph above for V[0], we should obtain :

[V[0],V[1],incoming:2,outgoing:0]

[V[0],V[2],incoming:1,outgoing:0]

[V[0],V[3],incoming:0,outgoing:1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin, a picture and graph description are nice, but a Gremlin script creating some sample data is even better:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('node').property(T.id,0).as('0').
  addV('node').property(T.id,1).as('1').
  addV('node').property(T.id,2).as('2').
  addV('node').property(T.id,3).as('3').
  addE('link').from('1').to('0').
  addE('link').from('1').to('0').
  addE('link').from('0').to('3').
  addE('link').from('2').to('0').iterate()
```

Here's one way to do this:

```
gremlin> g.V(0).bothE().
......1>   group().
......2>     by(union(inV(),outV()).fold()).
......3>     by(fold().
......4>        project('incoming','outgoing').
......5>          by(unfold().inV().hasId(0).count()).
......6>          by(unfold().outV().hasId(0).count()))
==>[[v[0],v[1]]:[incoming:2,outgoing:0],[v[0],v[2]]:[incoming:1,outgoing:0],[v[3],v[0]]:[incoming:0,outgoing:1]]
```

Basically, we `group()` each edge by its associated in/out vertices (line 2 - i.e. a `List` of in/out formed by `union().fold()`) and then reduce the edges that are gathered per vertex pair (starting at line 3). The reduce operation simply creates a list with `fold()` then uses `project()` to transform that `List` to a `Map` with "incoming" and "outgoing" keys - the values for those keys are defined in the following respective `by()` modulators (i.e. unfold the list of edges, filter for vertex "0" appropriately and `count()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Was struggling a bit doing chained groupcounts but the stored variables would be erased, I understood that reduction operations clear path history